# how to set region if points are there and find specific area?

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have all points to draw a line and display that points on canvas correctly. But now I want to draw another line on that exist line when touch by user. And my question is that how can find the user touch the inside that line or outside the line?

Answer (score 1):

I have a suggestion.

This is a thought based on Google Maps and Polylines but could should easily be adapted to a Canvas 2DLine situation too, I think.

Use this method to calculate the distance between two LatLng points:

```
/** distance in meters **/
private float distFrom(double lat1, double lng1, double lat2, double lng2) {
    double earthRadius = 3958.75;
    double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
    double dLng = Math.toRadians(lng2 - lng1);
    double a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2)
            + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1))
            * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) * Math.sin(dLng / 2)
            * Math.sin(dLng / 2);
    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
    double dist = earthRadius * c;

    int meterConversion = 1609;

    return (float) (dist * meterConversion);
}
```

When user clicks the canvas (for simplicity just imagine it has only one line):

- lineLength = Compute distance between the points (full length of the line)
- endToClickLength1 = Calculate distance from the click position to endpoint 1 of the line
- endToClickLength2 = Calculate distance from the click position to endpoint 2 of the line

Now, if endToClickLength1 + endToClickLength2 = lineLength (+/- acceptedError), then the user has clicked the line.

The acceptedError is needed to widen the boundary for when a lines is clicked a bit.

Do this for all the drawn lines to tell if one of the lines have been clicked.